# How to stop a running php process on heroku server?

Tags: php, heroku, phantomjs, paas

I have written a slack auto-message service on heroku that will auto send a message on some event. However, I have accidentally made an infinity loop and it keeps sending error message to my slack account. (the loop caused by retrying on error and I forgot to add a counter on that)

I have tried restarting the server by typing the command `heroku restart` (at that directory, so app name can be omitted), as well as git pushing my corrected version which should restart the server. I even turn off the server by settings 0 dymo to it. None of these works and I still keep receiving message on slack.

I am quite sure I have turn off my heroku server, so I think there should be other way to stop the process. The php process will have a `bash_exec` to trigger phantomjs. Not sure if it is related to the current problem. Do anyone has any suggestions?

P.S. As request, this is my code with important information hidden.

```
<?php
sendSlackMessageToChannel("Request received. Loading, please wait.");
startPhantomJS();
function startPhantomJS() {
    $return_value = bash_exec("path/to/phantomjs myscript.js");
    sendSlackMessageToMyself($return_value);
    if ($return_value == "error")
        startPhantomJS();
    else
        sendSlackMessageToChannel($return_value);
}
```

Comment: Give more information and code. This should be improved.

Comment: if it started again when you restarted the server, what starts this process running?

Comment: Added the code as requested.